# TFileStream write data to next line

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I'm manipulating TFileStream and I want to write data to next line.

Following code rewrites the previous one...

What can I do to wrap and make it write the new line there?

```
function TParserSkyecc.GenerateHTMLFile(pathHtml,out1,out2,out3,out4,out5 : String) : Boolean;
var FS: TFileStream;
begin
  FS := TFileStream.Create(pathHtml+'\filename.txt',fmCreate or fmOpenWrite or fmShareDenyNone);
  try
  FS.Seek(0,soFromBeginning);
    FS.WriteBuffer(Pointer(AnsiString(out1))^,Length(out1));
    FS.WriteBuffer(Pointer(AnsiString(out2))^,Length(out2));
    FS.WriteBuffer(Pointer(AnsiString(out3))^,Length(out3));
    FS.WriteBuffer(Pointer(AnsiString(out4))^,Length(out4));
    FS.WriteBuffer(Pointer(AnsiString(out5))^,Length(out5));
  finally
    FS.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: It's 2021 and web browsers *still* cannot execute native Pascal code...

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand It's not for web browsers, it's only to write data on .txt file by adding it to new line each time

Comment: I know! I was just kidding, since you inserted your code as an HTML+JavaScript snippet instead of a regular code block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simpler way to write this would be to use [`TStreamWriter`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TStreamWriter) instead of `TFileStream` directly. `TStreamWriter` takes a `TEncoding` in its constructor, and has a [`WriteLine()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TStreamWriter.WriteLine) method.  For example:

```pascal
function TParserSkyecc.GenerateHTMLFile(pathHtml,out1,out2,out3,out4,out5 : String) : Boolean;
var
  Filename: string;
  Writer: TStreamWriter;
begin
  Result := False;
  try
    Filename := IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(pathHtml) + 'filename.txt'; // or: TPath.Combine(pathHtml, 'filename.txt')
    Writer := TStreamWiter.Create(Filename, False, TEncoding.ANSI);
    try
      Writer.WriteLine(out1);
      Writer.WriteLine(out2);
      Writer.WriteLine(out3);
      Writer.WriteLine(out4);
      Writer.WriteLine(out5);
      Writer.Flush;
      Result := True;
    finally
      Writer.Free;
    end;
  except
  end;
end;
```

Alternatively, you can use `TStringList` instead:

```pascal
function TParserSkyecc.GenerateHTMLFile(pathHtml,out1,out2,out3,out4,out5 : String) : Boolean;
var
  Filename: string;
  SL: TStringList;
begin
  Result := False;
  try
    Filename := IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(pathHtml) + 'filename.txt'; // or: TPath.Combine(pathHtml, 'filename.txt')
    SL := TStringList.Create;
    try
      SL.Add(out1);
      SL.Add(out2);
      SL.Add(out3);
      SL.Add(out4);
      SL.Add(out5);
      SL.SaveToFile(Filename, TEncoding.ANSI);
      Result := True;
    finally
      SL.Free;
    end;
  except
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
uses System.Classes, System.SysUtils, System.IOUtils;

VAR pathHtml : STRING;

PROCEDURE Test(CONST TXT : STRING);
  VAR
    FS  : TStream;
    N   : TFileName;
    B   : TBytes;

  BEGIN
    N:=TPath.Combine(pathHtml,'filename.txt');
    IF NOT TFile.Exists(N) THEN
      FS:=TFileStream.Create(N,fmCreate OR fmShareDenyNone)
    ELSE BEGIN
      FS:=TFileStream.Create(N,fmOpenWrite OR fmShareDenyNone);
      FS.Position:=FS.Size
    END;
    TRY
      B:=TEncoding.ANSI.GetBytes(TXT);
      FS.WriteBuffer(B,LENGTH(B))
    FINALLY
      FS.Free
    END
  END;
```

Comments to implementation:

1. Use TPath.Combine to combine a directory and a File Name
2. Use TEncoding.ANSI.GetBytes to convert a UNICODE String to ANSI. The version you use above is faulty, as the AnsiString equivalent of a UNICODE String can be of a different length than the UNICODE String, f.ex. when you have national characters that are encoded in UNICODE as a pair but in AnsiString as a single byte, so you might end up (attempting to) write more bytes than the AnsiString conversion produces.
3. Be careful with AnsiString (and TEncoding.ANSI) as it is dependant on the language/region setting of the computer upon which the program is running.

If what Tom is saying in the comments:
*Asker wants to have the strings on separate lines in the file.*
is true, then it's quite simple. Just replace the lines

```
FS.WriteBuffer(Pointer(AnsiString(out1))^,Length(out1));
FS.WriteBuffer(Pointer(AnsiString(out2))^,Length(out2));
FS.WriteBuffer(Pointer(AnsiString(out3))^,Length(out3));
FS.WriteBuffer(Pointer(AnsiString(out4))^,Length(out4));
FS.WriteBuffer(Pointer(AnsiString(out5))^,Length(out5));
```

with

```
out1:=out1+#13#10; out2:=out2+#13#10; out3:=out3+#13#10;out4:=out4+#13#10; out5:=out5+#13#10;
FS.WriteBuffer(Pointer(AnsiString(out1))^,Length(out1));
FS.WriteBuffer(Pointer(AnsiString(out2))^,Length(out2));
FS.WriteBuffer(Pointer(AnsiString(out3))^,Length(out3));
FS.WriteBuffer(Pointer(AnsiString(out4))^,Length(out4));
FS.WriteBuffer(Pointer(AnsiString(out5))^,Length(out5));
```

to append a CR/LF to each line.

Comment: "as the AnsiString equivalent of a UNICODE String can be of a different length than the UNICODE String, f.ex. when you have national characters " That's wrong. A `UnicodeString` is a `UTF-16` string, so the byte count is always twice the character count. For instance, `Test` is encoded using eight bytes, every second being 0.

Comment: LENGTH <> SIZE :-)
It surprises me that you seem to be right :-). I'd have expected that U+0308 and U+0061 (umlaut Diacritical + the letter a) would be converted to a single Ansi character "ä" but it gets converted to 2 characters (¨a) instead, which I think is incorrect, but hey :-).

Comment: Even the UNICODE Diacritical characters that don't exist as a stand-alone character in Ansi (but the combination of this Diacritical + letter does exist in Ansi) are converted to "?a" and not to the "proper" combined character...

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand: Also, the byte count is not twice the character count, as U+0308 + U+0061 is *one* character (when displayed) but *two* code points (and thus four bytes). The correct statement is that byte count is always twice the code point count :-) A Character (in UTF-16) is not always equal to a single Code Point and certainly not to a single 16-bit word (there are more than 65536 characters in UNICODE, so even UTF-16 needs to use more than one 16-bit entity to describe certain characters). That's only true in UTF-32.

Comment: Doesn't seem to answer the question.

Comment: @TomBrunberg: Huh? It shows how to write a string to the end of a file instead of from the beginning. That's how I understand the phrase _I want to write data to next line._ How do you understand the question, then?

Comment: Askers current code writes the strings after each other. Asker wants to have the strings on separate lines in the file. Note: ***to next line***

Comment: @TomBrunberg: That's not how I read it, but anyway, I have told him how to do that as well... Note: to next line could just as easily mean (and that's how I understand it) the next line in the file, ie. append it to the end of the already existing lines...

Comment: Epsecially with his comment "rewrites" (there's no "rewrite" done due to missing CR/LF with the current code, as it always re-creates the file every time).

Comment: Actual question: *What can I do to wrap and make it write the new line there?* I leave it to you to understand it however you see fit.

Comment: What does _Following code rewrites the previous one..._ mean, then, if not the rewrite of the previous lines, ie. not appending, but overwriting?

Comment: I have nothing further to say. It's your answer.

Comment: @TomBrunberg: Only OP can say how the question was meant, but in any case, I have provided a reply to both interpretations...

Comment: @Marcol1no: If you simply want to have 5 lines in the file, and never more than 5, and always overwrite the lines with 5 new lines for each call, just use my second solution (appending a CR/LF sequence to each line before you write them out).

Comment: @HeartWare: Yes, but most of the time when I say "byte count is always twice the character count" I mean that `SizeOf(Char) = 2`, that is, the byte count of the string's character data is twice `Length(S)`. In any case, that's the interpretation that's relevant in this particular question!

Comment: @HeartWare I've read your solution right now and it works well but now I want to have more than 5 lines (no lines limit)

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand: UNICODE is a mess :-). Character Count vs. Code Points vs. Byte Count vs. String Length :-)

Comment: @Marcol1no: Use a TStringList or a CONST ARRAY OF STRING instead of a fixed parameter list out1..out5 - Ask a new question for that problem...

Comment: @HeartWare I've found how to have multiple rows in the same file. FS.Seek(0,soFromBeginning) brings me back always to the line[0]

Comment: @Marcol1no: You don't need the SEEK, since you are always re-creating the file on each call (fmCreate). The file is always opened at position 0, so there's no need to seek there - you're there already.